# Multiple In Clause that can be used in a JPA method

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Can we use two In clause and both will take list of integer in a JPA method. 
Ex: findByGroupIdAndUserId(List groupIdList, List userIdList)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple column with IN clause in not yet supported by Spring data.

You can use @Query annotation for custom query as below:

```
@Query( "select o from MyObject o where groupId in :gids and userId in :uids" ) 
List findByIds(@Param("gids") List groupIdList, @Param("uids") List userIdList);
```

Comment: In your spare time try to read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers